# Have multiple conditions in the LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method in C# that need to filter data based on 2 flags:

Active
IsBase
By default it should return active = true, IsBase= false.

This is the method I have in C#:

```
     public async Task<ICollection<Permission>> GetPermissions(bool? active = true, bool? 
       isBase = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var permissions = Array.AsReadOnly(
            await _ GetRepository<Permission>()
            .Query()
            .Where((active.HasValue ? x.active : x != null) && (isBase.HasValue ? x.isBase: x != null))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken));
        return permissions;
    }
```

This is my data:

| id | desc | active | IsBase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | test2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | test3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | test4 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | test5 | 1 | 0 |

I am passing active =0 and IsBase = 0. it should return nothing, but it returns line 1,2 and 3.

Comment: You have an operator precedence error. `?:` has lower precedence than `&&`. You need to add parentheses. `(active.HasValue ? x.active : x != null) && (isBase.HasValue ? x.isBase: x != null)`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you that works, but now when I pass both false, it should not return any records but it returns row 1 and 2 and 3.

Comment: If you pass false for both, then you select the ones that are both active and isBase, which is items 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: You are testing `active.HasValue` but not `active.Value` - whether you pass true or false, if you pass any value you are testing `x.active`. Did you mean something like `((active.HasValue && active.value) ? x.active : x != null)`? What did you intend each of the  three possible states of `active` to represent?

Comment: @NetMage: Probably supposed to be `(active.HasValue ? (active.Value == x.active) : (x != null))`

Comment: The code as written at the moment wouldn't compile as far as I can see - you're passing in `bool`, instead of a `Func<Permission, bool>` or the expression tree equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

If you pass both `false`:

```
(active.HasValue ? x.active : x != null) && (isBase.HasValue ? x.isBase: x != null)
```

will become `(false && false)`,

I thought you may try

```
.Where(x => x.active == active && x.isBase == isBase)
```